# How to pilot a custom widget through my event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BE3A2/2/) code :

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com">Translate (to italiano) piloting the Google Translate Tools</a>

<div id="boxSelLingue">
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: 'en'
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</div>        

<div id="myText">
    This is my text in the page to translate
</div>
```

how you can see, changing the language from the select box, the page will translate automatically. Now, I'd like to pilot this behaviour from another source; In the example, from the link *Translate (to italiano) piloting the Google Translate Tools*

So what I've done is :

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // I select the destination language, (it)alian
    var idLingua = "it";
    $('#boxSelLingue select').val(idLingua);
    $('#boxSelLingue select option').click();
});
```

how you can [see](http://jsfiddle.net/BE3A2/3/), clicking on the link change the selected value of the google select box, but I really don't know which event call the real google service (which should translate the page). I suppose it was change() or click(), but with :

```
    $('#boxSelLingue select option').click();
    $('#boxSelLingue select option').change();
```

nothing happens! In fact it doesnt works. The only way that google use to call his service (changing the value of select) is to attach an event handler on the select, in my opinion...

How can I do it?